# How much energy does it take to cook a steak?

Tags: thermodynamics, food

Grilling in the park today I started to wonder just how implausible a portable battery-powered grill would be. There are of course a lot of parameters in this question, so let's narrow it down for now: How much energy does it take to cook a steak?

To be a bit more specific let's say a 2.5cm thick steak to a core temperature of 63°C. And since we probably need one more measurement, let's say it's circular with a radius of 5cm.

Everything from numbers for cylindrical steaks in a vacuum to precisely the numbers that are needed to get an actual tasty steak would be interesting.

Comment: Assuming a similar specific heat capacity as water and starting at room temperature, it should be about 35 kJ which is slightly less than what my camera battery of 7.2 V and 1500 mAh can supply. So, it should be possible.

Comment: Your question is still not nearly precise enough. Count Iblis provided a lower limit under pretty much adiabatic conditions. Frying it in a normal pan will require approximately 1000kJ. Everything in between just depends on the conditions.

Comment: How fast do you want to cook it?  The cooking temperature is not necessarily designed to supply the energy for an endothermic reaction;  it may just speed up an exothermic reaction...

Comment: @Alexander : Of course it doesn't have all the necessary parameters. That was exactly why I was asking here. The comment by Count Iblis is a decent answer in the "spherical cow"-range even though I don't know if that is average temperature or core temperature. But 1000kJ for frying in a normal pan? How would I calculate that? Does that include the energy disappearing into the room? Does it include heat-up and cool-down? Is it an essentially nonsensical physics question no matter the assumptions that can only be properly answered by testing and measuring?

Comment: It is not a nonsensical question, it just has a large range of answers. 1000kJ comes from my stove, where a single burner uses 2kW and including warming up the pan such a steak might need 8 minutes (well done).

Comment: In theory, it is actually possible, as @CountIblis has said. However, if you talk about the practical aspect, it is not. As you will be cooking it on the pan, there will be loss of heat to the pan. Moreover, there will be loss of heat to the surroundings. Overall, too much heat will be lost and make this improbable at the least.

Comment: This is an excellent example of the type of question whose answers (in some undergrad physics course) should be graded on the quality of their approach, and not at all on the absolute value of the result produced.